# Access Https Rest Service using Spring RestTemplate (2 way SSL between client and server)

Tags: spring-boot

Can anybody provide me with a code sample to access rest service url secured with https using spring rest template.

I have the certificate(.pfx format)  password and send cient side certificate to server. server side  is used on the client side certificate  and established the connection 
I want to create a springboot application that work as 2 way SSL between client and server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I created a sample Spring Boot application that demonstrates how to create a `RestTemplate` that is configured for SSL client authentication. The sample application acts as the server as well which requires SSL mutual authentication (to demonstrate usage via the test case). In practice, the `RestTemplate` bean would interact with an external service. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/steve-oakey/spring-boot-sample-clientauth

I should note that the most important part of the example is creating the `SSLContext`. There are plenty of ways to create the `SSLContext`, I chose a method that uses the `SSLContextBuilder` from the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` library. Other methods such as using the Java API directly, or setting the `javax.net.ssl.*` JVM properties would also work.

Comment: Hi SteveO,Thanks for your help. I´m new to certificate based configuration, for 2 way SSL communication, I need only .pfx certificate and truststore.jks files. For my case, should I use truststore.jks or its different in my case.                   .loadKeyMaterial(loadPfx("classpath:client.pfx", password), password)

Comment: And in method .loadKeyMaterial(loadPfx("classpath:client.pfx", pfxpassword), password)- 1 is for .pfx password  and 2 password is for ¿ is it for truststore ¿ Kindly clarify asap.

Comment: Do I need to import my client .pfx certificate to my java truststore ?